# how do i get string from user wihtout know the leng, *wihtout use realloc or make high max leng before

Tags: c, string

how do I get **string from the user**, if I dont know the leng and **without use realloc or give max chars before**(char string[50]..) using C on visual studio

Answer (score 1):

You have somehow to provide storage for the string. There are two possibilities: static or dynamic. In both cases you have to set a maximum size up front if you cannot `realloc`.

Note that dynamic allocation could be hidden in a library function you could call to read the string.

So the answer to your question is: **You can't**.

But why would you do that? Just for the fun, a homework you have been assigned, or what?

Comment: hey thank you for the fast answer,
I do for universtiy project, and for be more clear i have optines to ask the user like what the size he need to , for the string for exmple..
for now the best thing i found is:
 ask the user for the size>malloc(/calloc as u wish)>rewind(stdin)>fgets()>rewind(stdin)

Answer (score 0):

You just guess the buffer size, make it reasonably big for the type of input you're getting. Then use `fgets()`:

```c
int size = 1024;
char example[size];

fgets(example, size, stdin);
```

If you have absolutely no idea how much data you're going to receive then you need to dump `stdin` to a temporary file, check that file's size, then read that back in.

If you're stuck with `char[50]` as a hard requirement, then you can only read 49 characters into a valid C string. You can always read in the input in chunks if necessary if you're prepared to discard it as you process it.